# Expected end of statement Error in Vb Script

Tags: vbscript

I am running vb script its showing error can anyone help what is the error i cannot find what is the error it shows error

Comment: Is this vba or vb.net?

Comment: Vba .................

Comment: @FloatingKiwi i tried but it still shows the same error

Comment: OK, VBA or VBScript?  You still have 2 different languages tagged.

Comment: `Dim bSendEmail : bSendEmail = true`

Comment: @Comintern its VbScipt

Comment: @JosefZ if i try this i am getting Object doesnt support this proprty or method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBScript doesn't have strong types.  Everything is `Variant`.  The error message in your edit is fairly clear as to the solution:

Line:4 Char:16 - Expected end of statement.

So looking at the code...

```
Dim bSendEmail as boolean = true
'             ^char 16
```

...it's telling you to end the statement there.  It should be:

```
Dim bSendEmail
bSendEmail = True
```

Comment: If i use this i am getting error in 22 line " object doesnt support this property or method"

Comment: @avi - Line 22 after what changes? If it's `myemail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")`, you're missing the `Set` at the start.  If it's another line, [the CDO documentation is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526130(v=exchg.10).aspx).

Comment: If  i change this line my logic is missing but previously its working after making changes in boolean not working. My aim is i am trying to check the folder for every 15 minutes where it generate 2 files for every 15 minutes if there are no files it should send email now after i change this line its sending email when i run the code doesnt matter whether file existis or not

Answer (score 0):

[`CreateObject` (Windows Script Host) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzysf6hc(v=vs.84).aspx) creates a COM object.

You need to use [`SET` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44(v=vs.84).aspx) to assign an object reference to a variable:

```
''' …
Dim bSendEmail: bSendEmail = True ''' colon instead new line: it's not a good practice
''' …

If bSendEmail Then
    ''' ↓↓↓          
        SET myemail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        ''' …
        SET myemail = Nothing
    ''' ↑↑↑
End If
```

Comment: If i change this line my logic is missing but previously its working after making changes in boolean not working. My aim is i am trying to check the folder for every 15 minutes where it generate 2 files for every 15 minutes if there are no files it should send email now after i change this line its sending email when i run the code doesnt matter whether file existis or not

Comment: @avi I don't understand your additional request. Ask another question, please; current question is considered to be answered…